# Wait for socketio event inside express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm using express,socketio and socketio-client in my application.
(I not very comfortable with nodejs stack...)

to summarize my application flow :
Client => node/express API + Socketoi server <=> nodejs (Socketio-client)

1. browser send request to a nodejs/express (route /api)
2. Do some request headers overwrites with middlewares
3. In the route '/', server sends an emit to a nodejs (Socketio-client)
4. after executing some logic, socketio-client emit an event with the logics result
5. **I need this result to be send in the response to the client**

My code below:

```
router.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  //emit data for socketio-client to apply some logic
  app.io.sockets.emit('req', {
    reqheader : req.headers,
    requrl : req.protocol + "://" + req.headers.host + req.url,
    reqmethod : req.method
  });
  console.log("after emit");
  //I use callback to make response wait for socketio server to catch event from client
  waitforevent(req, res, function (__res) {
    console.log("callback" );
    res.end(__res.body);
    res.sendStatus(__res.statusCode);
    //res.end();
  });
  function waitforevent(req, res, callback) {
    console.log("waiting for event" );
    app.io.__socket.on('respp', function (data) {
        //console.log("no response yet \n" + JSON.parse(data) );
        __res = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("event catched...");
        callback(__res);
    });
  }
});
```

**My problem** :
This works only the first time I send a Get http://localhost:3000/api frome the browser. **__res.body** is printed in the browser.

```
req 1
after emit
waiting for event
event catched...
callback
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.   
**GET /api 200 73.841 ms - -**

req 2
after emit
waiting for event
```

Next request will just wait for server to respond, which is, I suspect, not happening because the app.io.__socket.on('respp', function (data){...} is never catched by the server.

After sending more request (while the others are waiting), I noticed this warning in server logs:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 respp listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

**Is there other ways to catch events in a route before sending response to clients?**

Comment: can you share me the full code? The below answer isn't working anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the event listener when the socket closes to avoid the event listener leak:

```
router.get('/*', function (req, res) {
  app.io.sockets.emit('req', {
    reqheader : req.headers,
    requrl : req.protocol + "://" + req.headers.host + req.url,
    reqmethod : req.method
  });

  req.socket.on('close', function() {
    app.io.__socket.removeListener('respp', resppHandler);
  });
  app.io.__socket.on('respp', resppHandler);

  function resppHandler(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    res.statusCode = data.statusCode;
    res.end(data.body);
  }
});
```

I'm not sure if `app.io.__socket` should really be `app.io.sockets` or not, but I copied it as-is from your code, assuming you know what you're doing.

Additionally, you may wish to add some sort of timeout so as not to keep the request waiting indefinitely.

Comment: @mscdex I'm having the same issue. Above code didn't work. Can you pls help me with this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087400/forward-request-to-ws-client-and-wait-for-response-express/50087724?noredirect=1#comment87191366_50087724

Answer (score 2):

I solved with `once`:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var socket;
io.on('connection', function (sock) {
    console.log('Connected');
    socket = sock;
});

server.listen(3000);

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    socket.once('event', function (data) {
        if (data.error) {
            console.log('is an error');
            res.status(400).json(data);
        } else {
            console.log('is ok');
            res.status(200).json(data);
        }
    });
    io.emit('ask-for-event', { data: data });
});
```

Comment: Even though the explanation is basically missing, replacing ‘on’ with ‘once’ did solve the issue for me. I’m not sure why the event is emitted or catched more than once, but that seems the be the case. At least for me.