# Forward request to ws client and wait for response Express

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to build an endpoint that will receive a request, emit the request data to a WebSocket client, wait for an event, then send back the response using express + socketio. This question is similar to it: [Wait for socketio event inside express route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31992659/wait-for-socketio-event-inside-express-route)

1) Receive request at http://localhost:3000/endpoint

2) Emit the event to web sockets as 'req'

3) Wait for 'res' event from ws

4) Send the received events details as the response of express.

Here is how I'm implemented:

**server.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var socket;

io.on('connection', function (s) {
    socket = s;
});

http.listen(3000);

app.get('/endpoint', function (req, res) {
    console.log('new request')
    io.emit('req', { data: 'hello' });
    socket.on('res', function (data) {
        res.status(200).json(data);
    });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
    socket.on('req', (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        socket.emit('res', data);
    });
</script>
```

The script works fine for the first request on `/endpoint`. But if i hit the url again, it says

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
>   to the client

Comment: take your `socket.on('res'...)` out of the `app.get()`

Comment: ok. But then how can I send the res.send(). Its inside the app.get(), right? Is it possible to move it outside?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that:

```
socket.on('res', function (data) {
    res.status(200).json(data);
});
```

Is being called each time a socket is sending a response, thus showing the above error. You should unbind the listener inside the callback function.

Comment: How can I unbind it?

Comment: You may unbind a socket event by doing ` delete socket.$events[name]; ` . Also, in your case you should have maximum one socket client at any time.

Comment: can you suggest me a better approach what will work no matter how many socket clients / requests are there

Answer (score 1):

Keep an array of express responses and set an id to each request. So it can be used later and delete if needed.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var timeout = require('connect-timeout');
var uuid = require('uuidv4');
var _ = require('lodash');

app.use(timeout('10s'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

let responses = []

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('res', (e) => {
        var obj = _.find(responses, r => r.id === e.id);
        obj.res.send(e)
        _.remove(responses, r => r.id === e.id);
    })
})

app.get('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
    const id = uuid()
    io.emit('req', { id, ip: req.ip, header: req.headers, method: req.method });
    responses.push({ id, res })
});

http.listen(3000);
```

Comment: It should be working but I am not sure what would happen if you would do 2 parallel requests.

Comment: i don't recommend this at all but I'm too tired to convince you of our other two solutions lol

Comment: No, response in your case gets changed on each request.

Comment: @Theodor finally did it. Can you pls give me your feedback?

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to do two different async tasks for the same data.

First, take your `socket.on('res'...)` out of the `app.get()`.

Send back `res.status(200)` immediately with express to say you received the request and it is processing.  Then send the socket message to the client using socket.io when it's complete.  You'll want to save the connected users socket client ID and use `io.to(socketId).emit(...data...)` to do this

*the other option is what I always do (assuming it's not a crazy large payload of data you're sending)*  **Just use socket.io for the whole process.**

---

**client**

```
function makeRequest () {
    socket.on('data-complete--error', function ( error ) {
        // ... message to user :(
        // also remove these handlers when finished
        socket.off('data-complete--error');
        socket.off('data-complete--success');
    });
    socket.on('data-complete--success', function ( data ) {
        // ... message to user :)
        // ... handle data
        // also remove these handlers when finished
        socket.off('data-complete--error');
        socket.off('data-complete--success');
    });
    socket.emit('request-data');
}

makeRequest();
```

**server**

move your stuff out and handle without using express at all

Comment: I'm sending the request to the client, it will do some process on the request. And if it returns an error, I may need to send the response code 500 or something. So sending 200 everytime is not possible

Comment: You only send 200 as an initial "I received this request" acknowledgement.  Your error and success will be handled with different `socket.on('data-complete--error', ...)` and `socket.on('data-complete--success', ...)` handlers.

Comment: I tried. sending 200 first, it won't work. Browser immediately displays 200 with "OK"

Comment: Then do not use express for this.  Just use socket for this particular connection.  Or just use express and use `async/await`