# Send express response from outside asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

There is a function (similar to `setTimeout`, that works asynchronously) outside the express route. In my case, it's a function that listens for events from SocketIO. Is it possible to send the response from it?

```
setTimeout(() => {
 res.send('Got it');
}, 1000)

app.get('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
   // wait for event 'res' from setTimout
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to send the response from another function, you can just pass `res` to it for it to send the response.

If you need to do more work in the route, but only after the other function sends the response (why?), then you can change it to return a promise:

```
const someFunction = res =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res.send('Got it');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });

app.get('/endpoint', async (req, res) => {
  await someFunction(res);
  console.log('this will only be called after res sent');
});
```

Comment: I think this will not work in my real case. Can you pls check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087400/forward-request-to-ws-client-and-wait-for-response-express/50087724?noredirect=1#comment87191366_50087724

Comment: you can pass `res` as your emit data, then let the code in `io.on` send back the response.

Comment: i didn't get it. Can pls put it as an answer there

Comment: I tried: io.emit('req', {data: test, res: res});
But giving me an Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: add logging to see which function is being called recursively.