# Why am I unable to send response object of Express through SocketIO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to send the response to an express request by sending it to a ws client and wait for its response. So I need to send the `res` object to the client (I couldn't find another way).

Here is what I did:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('res', (e) => {
        e.res.send(e.data)
    })
})

app.get('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
    io.emit('req', { data: 'test', res: res });
});

http.listen(3000);
```

However, after going to /endpoint I'm getting this error:

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at Function.isBuffer (buffer.js:428:36)
>       at hasBinary (/workspace/socketio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:42:87)
>       at hasBinary (/workspace/socketio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:56:59)
>       at hasBinary (/workspace/socketio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:56:59)
>       at hasBinary (/workspace/socketio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:56:59)
>       at hasBinary (/workspace/socketio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:56:59)
>       at hasBinary (/workspace/socketio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:56:59)
>       at hasBinary (/workspace/socketio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:56:59)
>       at hasBinary (/workspace/socketio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:56:59)
>       at hasBinary (/workspace/socketio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:56:59)

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I unable to send response object of Express through SocketIO?

When objects are sent through socket.io, they are converted to JSON using `JSON.stringify()` (or something similar).  But `JSON.stringify()` has some requirements before it will work properly.  In particular, it only supports certain data types and it does not support circular references and I'm guessing that you have issues with both of those in the `res` object.

It is not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish here.  There is literally no reason at all to send the `res` object to your client.  Even if it could be stringified, there is nothing the client could do with that information anyway.  It's just housekeeping information from your server in order to send a response from the server and that info can only be used by the server itself, not by a client.

If you want to send a message to a client and wait for the client's response, then socket.io has a feature to do that.  It works by passing a callback as the 3rd argument to `.emit()` and then the client does something similar to craft its response.  You can see the documentation for this socket.io "ack" feature [here](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-emit-eventname-args-ack).

Comment: got it. This is what I'm trying to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50087400/forward-request-to-ws-client-and-wait-for-response-express/50087724

Comment: It only confirms that client has received it. Is it possible to manipulate the data and sent back as ack?

Comment: @GijoVarghese - Yes, you can send data, have the client modify it and send it back as an ack.  But, the data you send has to be just data, not a live `res` object.  So, just send whatever property you want the client to modify as data and then have the client send something back that your server can then use.  If you look at the documentation example carefully, the client can send data back with the ack.

Comment: ok. I tried that. But got an error "Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting"

Comment: @GijoVarghese - That's true.  You need to be sending to one particular client with `socket.emit(...)`, not all clients.  This makes sense too because you need to be waiting for one client to respond, not all clients.

Comment: @GijoVarghese - I'm wondering why when you get a request from a client you then have to ask the client for more information before sending the response.  It seems the client should just supply the missing information with the request (perhaps as a query parameter).  Why can't the request just stand on its own, containing enough information.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170057/discussion-between-gijo-varghese-and-jfriend00).