# How to use socket io inside class

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to create game using socket io. I want to implement socket inside server.js but I would like to keep events inside Room.js.:

server.js

```
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server)

io.sockets.on('connection', socket => {
   socket.on('join room', data => {
       let room = new Room(data.id, socket)

       socket.join(`room${data.id}`)
   }
}
```

Room.js

```
class Room{
   constuctor(id, socket){
      this.id = id,
      this.socket = socket,
      this.handlerOfEvents()
   }
   handlerOfEvents() {
      this.socket.on('new player connected', data => {
        console.log('New player connected!')
      }
   }
}
```

I tried do as above but it doesn't work:

```
 \node_modules\has-binary2\index.js:30
function hasBinary (obj) {
                   ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Is there any solution to do sth like this? 
Or maybe there is another perfect way to implement events for particular room.

This problem occurs when I try assign `socket` to `this.socket` but when I put it directly as argument like below:

```
class Room{
       constuctor(id, socket){
          this.id = id,
          //this.socket = socket,
          this.handlerOfEvents(socket)
       }
       handlerOfEvents(socket) {
          socket.on('new player connected', data => {
            console.log('New player connected!')
          }
       }
    }
```

then just invoke this method in `server.js`

```
socket.on('joined new player', data => {
   ...
   room.handlerOfEvents(socket)
}
```

so, this solution is working for now. But if this is proper way?
Issue from link in comments didn't solve my problem unfortunately.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: How exactly "doesn't it work"?

Comment: There is some error in the console. I edited my question. Sorry for missed error detail

Comment: Try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093188/why-am-i-unable-to-send-response-object-of-express-through-socketio - similar error. You possibly have a reference circle in your structure and that exahusts your call stack.